# What has made Adobe Flex more “acceptable” than its predecessors?

Tags: apache-flex, activex, adobe, java-web-start

I have been building enterprise software for the last 10 years.  In this time we have seen enterprise applications move from client server to thin clients.  We have also seen the move to hosted solutions, albeit under a few names (asp, SaaS, cloud computing).  With all these changes the impetuous has been mainly from driven from the IT department not the end user.  In the first rounds of these revolutions the user experience was reduced in the name of single point of management and reduced desktop footprint.

During this time there have been many attempts to give the user a rich experience while still satisfying the crotchety IT department.  The first was by the industry leader Microsoft in the form of the ActiveX control.  The guys from Sun then followed suit with the applet and then more recently java webstart.  All of these solutions seemed to scratch the itch but never gained wide expectance by the more stringent IT departments.

Then flex came on the scene from Macromedia.  What did they do differently?  Is it sustainable?  Does Microsoft’s emulation with Silverlight prove they have changed the rules of the game?  Will Web programming be changed forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Adobe have succeeded because almost all users of the main browsers on the main platforms already have installed the only runtime component required for Flex; which is the Flash player. The Flash player has already demonstrated that it isn't a vector for Bad Stuff; it runs in its own sandbox in the browser, isolated from the hardware and the OS. So no new (and potentially dangerous) software is installed.
2. There exists a substantial developer community for Flash technology, and the addition of some new controls in Flash, and maturity in ActionScript for writing software, has tipped it over the threshold for being fully useful as a RUI.

   (Activex is Windows-0nly; Anything in java is perceived as destabilizing and too heavy; and java hasn't managed to wangle its way into ubiquity, nor will it probably ever do so. So both generally get installed by edict, rather than user choice. This in spite of the fact that Adobe is probably the most disruptive source of unrequested "update-checkers" and other near-malware we deal with in our ecosystem.)
3. Microsoft started out with Silverlight pretty aggressively, requiring only the installation of the equivalent of the Flash runtime; but it's not ubiquitous even on Windows machines yet; penetration to other platforms is quite a way in the future; and MS hasn't proven to have the political smarts to appear harmless yet. But don't count it out. I think they've moved a step back by switching to .NET languages (with a limited CLR) for development; this seems to me to be the same strategy that has deoxygenated their WinCE strategy; but again we'll see. But at least they have made an obvious move away from language agnosticism to appearing to want to coerce developers into .NETland.
4. Web programming is changing forever one way or another; users will demand a better, more fine-grained UI; there's no perfect answer in sight yet, but at least there is competition for hearts and minds. I think the most encouraging signs come from Microsoft's strong move into platform-neutral stuff like MVC, Iron Stuff, and increasingly unpolluted code streams to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

My take on Flex's success:

1- Adobe made the right move in opensourcing not only AIR, but Flex, the Flash VM, and the PDF standard now as well.

2- Flex's rich Flash heritage (it runs on any Flash enabled browser) means that the vast majority of browsers already support it and do not need to download a large plugin to access it.

3- Adobe embraced all the major server-side technologies and provided support for them so that a PHP. MS, or Java shop would all feel comfortable using Adobe's client side technology.

Previously, Flex was closed-source, expensive, and even relied on a server-side installation, which negated it's reach even though the Flash client was so widely available.

Answer (score 0):

- YouTube and the general ubiquity of
  Flash video entrenched the Flash
  player into over 95% of the browsers
  that are accessing the public
  Internet.
- Incorporating Flex GUI for form
  design with widgets and an extremely
  well designed GUI SDK was a major
  turning point for the Flash player.
  Flex 2 and Flashplayer 9 were the
  tipping points of when this
  technology really jelled. Enterprise
  developers began to quickly realize
  that this technology was just the
  right approach for doing their
  applications. (At JavaOne in 2006,
  Adobe Flex 2 was the most impressive
  and pivatol technology that I saw
  there.)
- The Flash runtime has just enough
  stuff to run RIA GUI well in a web
  browser sandbox setting - Java
  applets required the full JRE (about
  16 MB). The Flash runtime was a much
  leaner and smarter design for its
  intended purpose. (Sun has only now
  begun to remedy this for Java via
  their JavaFX and redesigned JRE that
  can download a few MB as sufficient
  to run a web applet. They don't have
  anything like YouTube Flash video to
  drive their installations, though.)
- Writing Flex RIA applications is a
  very leveraged experience compared
  to writing old-school web
  HTML/JavaScript AJAX apps. Can
  achieve a great deal more and have
  less effort to accomplish such.
- Adobe bolstered Flex with other
  important pieces, such as BlazeDS
  (and now they're cooperating with
  SpringSource to make BlazeDS and
  Spring-Framework a smoother
  integration).
- The single-thread GUI in combination
  to async service calls (or
  messaging), and ActionScript3
  closures is great programming model:

  [Flex Async I/O vs Java and C#
  Explicit Threading](http://humbleblogger.blogspot.com/2008/05/flex-async-io-vs-java-and-c-explicit.html)
- Likewise, Adobe Flex has a great
  implementation of properties,
  events, and databinding.
- A declarative language, ala MXML, is
  indeed a better approach to
  describing a form (what is
  essentially the view in the MVC
  pattern). It is more concise than
  equivalent imperative ActionScript
  code that would accomplish the same
  thing, and thus clearer. The
  hierarchical structure of MXML
  script tends to naturally match well
  to the panel/widget construction of
  views as well.
- With Flex RIA approach, the MVC
  pattern can be implemented
  completely on the client tier. Web
  frameworks that implemented MVC in
  the middle-tier - with the
  presentation layer executing in the
  remote client-tier, was a
  fundamentally flawed approach to
  MVC. MVC should be done right at the
  tier that is directly user-facing.
  (Once again, Adobe Flex does things
  right architecturally.)
- Despite that HTML/DOM/JavaScript is
  considered the pervasive standard of
  the Internet web, the Adobe Flash
  player is actually a more ubiquitous
  and consistent standard - spanning
  different browsers and operating
  system platforms. The
  HTML/DOM/JavaScript standard is in
  actuality a fragmented mess that
  grows more fragmented everyday as
  Google and Microsoft drive different
  directions on things regarding the
  web browser. Adobe Flash player ends
  up being a wonderful end-run around
  this dilemma. It's a great
  programming experience for the
  coders and has sufficient ubiquity
  for the business suits.
- Adobe is smartly well supporting the
  major platforms of Windows, Mac OS
  X, and Linux. They pay special
  attention to the Linux platform.
  This will pay off in the long term
  as developers are already settling
  on Linux to do their development
  from, and it's used extensively for
  servers hosting their middle-tier.
  Adobe's recent 64-bit Flash player
  for Linux is just a marvel. They
  already have AIR 1.5 available on
  Linux. They are doing a decent job
  there of supporting the platform
  that the developers care about.